# Not able to insert the multiple record in database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a form(like Invoice) with orderno,order date, Stationerytype,stationery quantity field here stationerytype and stationery qty cam be more than one. I am trying to insert the data in my table but my insert button not working.Submit button is not reacting and not inserting any value into table.My code is lengthy plz bear with it

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include('includes/config.php');
if(strlen($_SESSION['alogin'])==0)
    {   
header('location:index.php');
}
else{
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    for($count = 0; $count < count($_POST["item_name"]); $count++)
{   
$txntype='received';
$orderno=$_POST['orderno'];
$orderdate=$_POST['orderdate'];   
$stationerytype=$_POST['item_unit']; 
$stationeryqtyrecd=$_POST['item_quantity']; 

$sql="INSERT INTO tblstationerystock(txntype,orderno,orderdate,stationerytype,stationeryqtyrecd) VALUES(:txntype,:orderno,:orderdate,:stationerytype,:stationeryqtyrecd)";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':txntype',$txntype,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':orderno',$orderno,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':orderdate',$orderdate,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':stationerytype',$stationerytype[$count],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':stationeryqtyrecd',$stationeryqtyrecd[$count],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$lastInsertId = $dbh->lastInsertId();
if($lastInsertId)
{
$msg="Stationery Stock added Successfully";
header('location:dashboard.php');
}
else 
{
$error="Something went wrong. Please try again";
}

}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        
                
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <br />
        <div class="container" style="border: 2px solid #B22222;border-radius: 10px;margin-top: 25px;margin-bottom: 15px;>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <h4 align="center"><b><u>Add Stationery Stock<b></u></h4>
                    <br />
                    <form method="post" id="insert_form">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" name="orderno." class="form-control" placeholder="Order NO "/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="date" name="orderdate" class="form-control" placeholder="Date" />
                    </div>
                    &nbsp;
                    <div>&nbsp;</div>
                    <div>&nbsp;</div>
                    <h4 align="center"><b><u>Stationery Details<b></u></h4>
                    <div>&nbsp;</div>
                    
                        <div class="table-repsonsive">
                            <span id="error"></span>
                            <table class="table table-bordered" id="item_table">
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="width:10%">Sl.No.</th>
                                    <th style="width:50%">Select Unit</th>
                                    <th>Enter Quantity</th>
                                    <th><button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-sm add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></th>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <div align="center">
                                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info"style="margin-bottom:20px" >ADD</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript  code

```
const renum = () => {
  let cnt = 0;
  $(".item_name").each(function() {
    this.value = ++cnt;
  })
};

$(function() {

  $("#item_table").on('click', '.add', function() {
    var html = '';
    html += '<tr>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="item_name[]"  class="form-control item_name"  readonly></td>';
    html += '<td><select name="item_unit[]" class="form-control item_unit" id="datalist"><option value="">Select Stationery Type</option><option value="A4 Green Ream">A4 Green Ream</option></select></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="item_quantity[]" class="form-control number_only item_quantity" /></td>';
    html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';
    $('#item_table').append(html);
    renum()
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    renum()
  });

  $('#insert_form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var error = '';
    $('.item_name').each(function() {
      var count = 1;
      if ($(this).val() == '') {
        error += "<p>Enter Item Name at " + count + " Row</p>";
        return false;
      }
      count = count + 1;
    });

    $('.item_quantity').each(function() {
      var count = 1;
      if ($(this).val() == '') {
        error += "<p>Enter Item Quantity at " + count + " Row</p>";
        return false;
      }
      count = count + 1;
    });

    $('.item_unit').each(function() {
      var count = 1;
      if ($(this).val() == '') {
        error += "<p>Select Unit at " + count + " Row</p>";
        return false;
      }
      count = count + 1;
    });
    var form_data = $(this).serialize();
    if (error == '') {
      $.ajax({
        url: "insert.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: form_data,
        success: function(data) {
          if (data == 'ok') {
            $('#item_table').find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
            $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-success">Item Details Saved</div>');
          }
        }
      });
    } else {
      $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + error + '</div>');
    }
  });

});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('keypress', '.number_only', function(e){
return isNumbers(e, this);      
});
function isNumbers(evt, element) 
{
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
if (
(charCode != 46 || $(element).val().indexOf('.') != -1) &&      // “.” CHECK DOT, AND ONLY ONE.
(charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
return false;
return true;
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: At a quick glance, start by checking `$_POST['orderno']` with the `name="orderno."` where that dot shouldn't be in there.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Thnx i corrected that still it is not working The submit button is not at all reacting to clcik

Comment: Sure thing. Well this `error_reporting(0);` doesn't help you. Enable error reporting and check for errors on the query https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php and look at the developer console for the JS stuff. Best I can offer for this.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner my form is working fine including fine including JS.Problem started when i inserted the query for mysql. If i click on Insert button it does not react .

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that you're checking:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

From Jquery docs ([Jquery serialize() doc](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)) -

> Note: Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button

So, you're checking for an element that isn't posted.

Instead, you could do:

```
if(isset($_POST['item_name']))
```

or better yet:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

Comment: Not sure why my answer is not useful. It should resolve the 'submit' action and insert the record(s) to the db table. There are other issues with the code, but I would think that's beyond the scope of the question. If there are issues with my answer, I'd like to know why.